# Do I have to use the 'one standard error from minimum CV error' rule?

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, elastic-net

I have just spent a decent amount of time learning how to do a stacked adaptive elastic net regression on several multiply-imputed datasets using the `saenet` package.

I understand that recommended practice is to use the value of lambda within one standard error of the minimum cross validation error. When I use the lambda value that yields the minimum CV error itself several of the predictors are non-zero. However when I use the 1SE value of lambda, *all* the predictors are zero.

Is there any empirical reason forbidding me from choosing the model with the minimum CV error rather than 1SE from minimum?

Comment: No, you absolutely don't *have to* pick the lambda that obeys the one-standard error rule. It's just that in a situation like this, it looks like the trivial model is competitive with the one with minimum CV error.